# Como obtener support en sklearn.metrics.classification_report

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy utilizando `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` y me gustaría poder aislar los valores `support` para trabajar con ellos por separado, pero no se como extraerlos. La llamada la realizo con  `print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names)).`

```
Logistic regression using RBM features:
         precision    recall  f1-score   support

      0       0.99      0.99      0.99       174
      1       0.92      0.95      0.93       184
      2       0.95      0.98      0.97       166
      3       0.97      0.91      0.94       194
      4       0.97      0.95      0.96       186
      5       0.93      0.93      0.93       181
      6       0.98      0.97      0.97       207
      7       0.95      1.00      0.97       154
      8       0.90      0.88      0.89       182
      9       0.91      0.93      0.92       169

avg / total       0.95      0.95      0.95      1797
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Te damos la Bienvenida a StackOverflow en Español. Te invito a que pases por el [Recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leas el artículo [Cómo Preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Podrías compartir el código con el que estás trabajando para poder darte una mano ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La salida de `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` es una cadena. Partamos de unos datos como base para reproducir el problema:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
```

**Salida:**

> ```
>              precision    recall  f1-score   support
>
>     class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
>     class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
>     class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3
>
> avg / total       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
> ```

Tienes varias opciones, entre ellas:

- Usar [`sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) que retorna arrays de NumPy que podemos obtener mediante indexación:

  ```
  from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support

  y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
  y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
  target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']

  res = precision_recall_fscore_support(y_true, y_pred)
  support = res[3]
  print(support)
  ```

  **Salida:**

  > [1, 1, 3]

  Es un array de NumPy de tipo `int64`
- Parsear el string de salida de `sklearn.metrics.classification_report` de forma apropiada:

  ```
  from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

  y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
  y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
  target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']

  res = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names)
  support = [int(fila.split()[-1]) for fila in res.split('\n')[2:-3]]
  print(support)
  ```

  **Salida:**

  > [1, 1, 3]

  Se trata en este caso de una lista de Python pero se puede pasar facilmente a array de NumPy si se prefiere.